# SQLiteConnection statement error

Tags: sqlite

I am getting a blue squiggly under this line which starts with SQLiteConnection, not sure what i am missing. I was using SQLiteAsyncConnection, since I read somewhere that it doesn't support methods like InsertWithChildren, thought of trying out the SQLiteConnection class.

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
    SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
```

These are the using statements I have on top:

```
using SQLite.Net;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions;
```

And this is the error message I am getting

```
Error 2 'SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments D:\OneDrive\Projects\SQLiteAsyncConnection Class\sqlite-net\MainPage.xaml.cs 28 31 sqlite-net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a constructor from another library - the basic "sqlite-net" requires only a single parameter constructor, but SQLite.Net requires a platform parameter aswell. [Here](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) you can find documentation and constructor example:

```
public class Database : SQLiteConnection
{
    private const string DATABASE_NAME = "sqlite.db";
    private static ISQLitePlatform platform = new SQLitePlatformWin32();

    public Database()
        : base(platform, DATABASE_NAME)
    {
        CreateTable<ClassExample>();
    }
}
```